# Combine a variable with variable value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, scope, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to do something like this in Angular javascript (a simplified code):

```
var modelName = "date";

if (attrs.hasOwnProperty('today')) {
   scope.modelName = new Date();
}
```

In the above, I actually want `scope.modelName` to become `scope.date` automatically. How can I parse the `modelName` variable to its value?

Comment: You mean `scope[modelName] = new Date()` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access properties of objects using square brackets.

```
var modelName = "date";

if (attrs.hasOwnProperty('today')) {
   scope[modelName] = new Date();
}
```

Comment: MDN: ["Properties of JavaScript objects can also be accessed or set using a bracket notation."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

Comment: yeah... that seems about right. However, in Angular, the new Date() is not updating the ng-model box when I have it as `scope[modelName]`. However if I type it directly as `scope.date` then it works.

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle? I'll look over it.

Comment: I just tried it in jsFiddle and it works there. It doesnt work in my code only. So I need to review my code and see if I had done a mistake anywhere. Thank you so much for telling me how to access properties of objects. That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks heaps.. :)

Comment: @user2708395 I found out why it wasnt working on my code. It works if I have `modelName = "date"` but it doesnt work if the `modelName = "formData.date"`. I have a jsfiddle here that shows a sample. Is this not allowed? Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/6fJdk/2/

Comment: Ahh to do that you would do this: scope['formData']['date']. So you need to store them as separate variables.

Comment: Quick question, on the jsFiddle is that what you want to achieve or just a simplified test case? You can do all that without a directive.

Comment: Its just a simplified case.

Comment: when I tried `scope['formData']['one'] = new Date();` in the jsfiddle example, it is not working yet.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/6fJdk/3/ I think it wasn't working because you didn't have formData defined in the controller. Without the definition, formData would be undefined, and so trying to access the property one would fail.

Comment: aha... it makes sense now. Also I think I am better off adding `new Date()` defined in the controller rather than adding it via directive after checking for `today` attribute etc.. Thank you so much. Your answers and yours sample helped a lot. Cheers!