# Returning an array containing named properties of each object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Just getting stumped and not sure why my code isn't working. The instructions are to take an array of objects and a property name, and return an array containing the named property of each object.
so something like`pluck([{a:1}, {a:2}], 'a') // -> [1,2]` where pluck is the function I want to create.

So far, I have:

```
function pluck(objs, name) {
  var pushedArray=[];
  for (i=0;i<objs.length;i++){
    var totalpushedArray = pushedArray.push(name[i]);
  }
}
```

but the code itself isn't working as far as I can tell. There are additional guidelines to leave `undefined` if the object doesnt have the property but I figure that I will get to that after I solve this first.

Comment: btw, use `for(var i` instead of `for(i=0`. Right now your `i` var is global!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add a return statement and you're not referencing the object property. See below.

```
function pluck(objs, name) {
    var pushedArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
        pushedArray.push(objs[i][name]);
    }
    return pushedArray;
};
```

If you want a more "functional" solution, you can use map.

```
function pluck(objs, name) {
    return objs.map(function(obj) {
        return (obj.hasOwnProperty(name) ? obj[name] : null);
    });
};
```

Comment: Why is the syntax .push(objs[i][name]);

Comment: `objs[i]` means object at index `i`. `objs[i][name]` means object property `name` of object at index `i`. In JavaScript you can reflect or access properties by their string name using the square bracket notation. [This might help explain it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671770/combine-a-variable-with-variable-value-in-javascript/22671818#22671818)

Comment: Am i just going about this the wrong way? I thought syntax for accessing object properties was either `name person.lastName` or `name = person["lastName"]`. However, if I think about that in terms of what you wrote, won't it be something like a[a]?

Comment: as in, if you look at `pluck([{a:1}, {a:2}], 'a') // -> [1,2]`, isn't `obj[i]` `a` at every point in the array? and the `name` is a as well

Comment: The argument supplied to pluck is an array of objects. So that's why the reference is `objs[i]` because `objs` is an array and `objs[i]` is the object. So to reference the object's property, you then use `objs[i][name]`. Does that make sense?